# Turn on Parental Lock from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

Is it possible to turn on the parental lock from an iPhone or iPad app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. It's a system-wide setting and apps do not get access to it.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the fast response!